# how to take data from session and insert to another table in asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, razor

How to take data from session and insert to another table in asp.net mvc4?
already I have session variable using that variable I want to insert data to another table.

Comment: Post some code for understanding what issue you are facing

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do ?? Values in sessions dont get flushed by default unless you do so or a time out occurs ... You could still use same Session["xyz"] variable to insert data to your second table also.

```
Table1.Name = Session["Name"];
Table2.Name = Session["Name"];
```